# How China's Weibo deleted text from my video?

Tags: graphics

I made a home 45 min video of myself giving a presentation on a physics topic using my iphone 6. The format is quicktime .MOV - about 2.8 GB. I converted it to .mp4,down to 650MB,using a software avidemux.

After that I used a linux utility ffmpeg and used a 'drawtext' feature to add relevant  text/equations at relevant portions of my video. This is a .mpeg-4 to .mpeg-4  with little change in size  I understand it may be similar to a hard-sub with re-endcoding (I don't understand what is re-encoding). I uploaded it to youtube and China's youku and everything was working find.

I then made a post in China's Weibo (an equivalent to Twitter) with a link to my youku video. I got a surprise! The video plays perfectly, but somehow all the text that I added with 'drawtext' disappeared. I don't understand.

I know that Weibo is heavily censored, but I can't understand if somehow they would go to this extend. They might as well take away my audio track or delete my video link.

I ask a relative of mine who has a B.Sc in computer science and he told me there are ways using AI neural network to remove texts from my video. The text from my video is very clear with blue and a ttf font style.

Can someone confirm this is what Weibo did to my video, censoring all the texts. If true, how could I redo my video so that no one could remove the texts. I have the original .MOV files

Comment: We can't possibly know what exactly they do, and technical details of software are offtopic here.

Comment: That said, note that using OCR detecting text is probably next to trivial.